# Making elements non-editable in Struts using jQuery

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am using Struts and jQuery for one of my web applications. In one of the screens, some elements need to be disabled based on certain conditions. For ex, If a val of variable **test** is "Employee", then a drop down box (select box in struts) should be disabled. User should not be allowed to select a value. System will assign a value based on the value in variable **test**.

I tried to use the following options.

1. `$("#selectBox").prop('disabled','disabled');`
2. `$("#selectBox").prop('disabled',true);`
3. `$("#selectBox").prop('readonly','readonly');`
4. `$("#selectBox").prop('readonly',true);`

I used the method attr to set the values. The disabled attribute makes the dropdown non-editable, but the values are not set into the struts bean and so the values are not available in the Action class. The last 2 options did not make the drop down non-editable.

How to make the struts elements like select box, check box non-editable in jQuery on conditional basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the disabled attr with true, and use a input hidden field to submit the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please share the sample code for that?

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="selectBoxReal" name="selectBoxReal" />
<select id="selectBox"></select>

$("#selectBoxReal").val($("#selectBox").val());
$("#selectBox").prop('disabled',true);


then the selectBoxReal's value will submit;

Comment: Thanks for the code. I already fixed it using the hidden variable. Anyways thanks for ur help.